# How to make the screen fade

Tags: android

I would like the user to be able to click on the screen.

On click, I would like entire screen to turn opaque slowly.

Then I would like to display some buttons on the opaque screen.

What is the best way to achieve this effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could fade in a dialog with an opaque background.
Then just set a custom view that contains your buttons on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options I found

[ViewSwticher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html)

[CrossFade](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html)

**edit**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533731/fade-effect-between-layouts) method to be ideal for cross-fading layouts.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply change the alpha level of the activity's background in order to give it an opaque effect.

```
View backgroundimage = findViewById(R.id.my_activity);
Drawable background = backgroundimage.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(50);
```

To make it appear to "fade out", you could easily implement this into a for loop, allowing the thread to sleep for a short time between intervals to create an animated effect.

Here is a quick design of what this function might look like:

```
void fadeView(View v, int threshold, int speed) {
    Drawable background = v.getBackground();

    for (int i = 100; i < threshold; i--) {
        background.setAlpha(i);
        Thread.sleep(speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you don't sleep on the UI thread. Use View.postDelayed() instead.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, haven't played with Android in awhile.